# Changing the text of an element when referencing it from an array

Tags: angularjs, cordova

I'm trying to change text elements in a page based on numerical values I pass back from my server. I manage to store each reference as well as the value from the server, but when trying to access to the text value of the object I get hit with the error `statusText[key].text is not a function`. is it possible to access the object properties when referencing from a list? Javascript and Angular are not my strong suits.

Here's the code:

```
var log = [];
var statusText = [];

$http.post("url", {userid: currentUserID})
.then(function(response)
{
    angular.forEach(response.data.status, function(value, key){
        this.push(value.complete);
    }, log);

    angular.forEach(document.getElementsByClassName("step-status"), function(value, key)
    {
        this.push(value)
    }, statusText);

    angular.forEach(statusText, function(value, key)
    {
        if (log[key] == 2)
        {
            statusText[key].text('Completed');
        }
        else if (log[key] == 1)
        {
            statusText[key].text('In progress');
        }
        else
        {
            statusText[key].text('Not started');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var log = [];
var statusText = [];

$http.post("url", {userid: currentUserID})
.then(function(response)
{
    angular.forEach(response.data.status, function(value, key){
        this.push(value.complete);
    }, log);

    angular.forEach(document.getElementsByClassName("step-status"), function(value, key)
    {
        this.push(value)
    }, statusText);

    angular.forEach(statusText, function(value, key)
    {
        if (log[key] === 2)
        {
            statusText[key] = 'Completed';
        }
        else if (log[key] === 1)
        {
            statusText[key] = 'In progress';
        }
        else
        {
            statusText[key] = 'Not started';
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: unfortunately all this does is change the array entry to a string.

Comment: What are you trying to do? You cannot access an array like a function `statusText[key].text('')`.

Comment: I'm trying to set the text property of the elements I have stored in that array.

Comment: Have you tried `statusText[key].innerHTML = 'Completed'`?

Answer (score 0):

Sollution: Changed my approach for displaying the returned strings. Just set each element of the array to the string I want and used bindings to display the data.

Thanks for the help all.